# How can I be notified when Google Maps My Location layer loses user location?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, mylocationoverlay

After calling [`setMyLocationEnabled(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setMyLocationEnabled%28boolean%29) on a GoogleMap, I see a blue dot indicating the user's current location. If I disable GPS and enable airplane mode, this blue dot remains visible on the map for 1-2 minutes before disappearing (and, naturally, the My Location button ceases to function).

I expected that I would be able to figure out when the dot disappeared by watching the [`onConnectionSuspended(int cause)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.html#onConnectionSuspended%28int%29) callback that I specified when building the `GoogleApiClient` as described [in the FusedLocationProviderApi documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html):

```
new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .build()
```

However, this callback does not seem to be invoked when I disable all location-providing components on my phone (thereby causing the blue dot to disappear). Is there a different callback I should be using to receive this information? If not, is rolling a custom LocationSource implementation a feasible/reasonable way to ensure my map UI can remain synced with other location-dependent UI in the rest of my app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24804652/gpsstatus-switch-between-gps-event-started-and-gps-event-stopped/24812401#24812401    Been there had much better luck using a broadcastreceiver

Comment: Thanks for the link. If my understanding is correct, that won't necessarily fire at the same time as the user location is actually removed from the map, right? Still, definitely a solution I'll think about.

Comment: the broadcastreceiver fires instantly when the gps is changed on or off.  What you do with it is up to you.  For example I just put a button on the map.  You might turn off the location blue dot.